# specified cast is not valid in casting int to byte

Tags: c#, .net, linq

i have an entity named:AttachmentType which has a property ShowDuringRegistration as byte

with executing this line i always see this error :specified cast is not valid,, no matter that i'm sending a byte as parameter

```
Repository<AttachmentType>.FindBySpecification(new AttachmentSearchSpecification()
    .WithTraceCodeOrNationalNumber(traceCodeString)
    .WithAttachmentTypeShowDuringRegistration(false))
    .Select(p=>new attachmentTypeModel()
     {
       Id=p.Id,
       Title=p.Title
     })
    .ToList();

 public AttachmentSearchSpecification WithAttachmentTypeShowDuringRegistration(bool showDuringRegistration=false)
 {          
      AddExpression(p => p.AttachmentType.ShowDuringRegistration == (showDuringRegistration ? 1 : 0));
      return this;
 }
```

even if i send a byte to WithAttachmentTypeShowDuringRegistration method and compare ShowDuringRegistration  with that property it doesn't work

```
byte b=0;
Repository<AttachmentType>.FindBySpecification(new AttachmentSearchSpecification()
    .WithTraceCodeOrNationalNumber(traceCodeString)
    .WithAttachmentTypeShowDuringRegistration(b))
    .Select(p=> new attachmentTypeModel()
     {
       Id=p.Id,
       Title=p.Title
     })
    .ToList();

public AttachmentSearchSpecification WithAttachmentTypeShowDuringRegistration(byte showDuringRegistration)
{
    AddExpression(p => p.AttachmentType.ShowDuringRegistration == showDuringRegistration)
    return this;
}
```

here is when the error raises:

```
select cast(count(*) as INT) 
as col_0_0_ from EmploymentRegistration.[Attachment]
attachment0_, EmploymentRegistration.[Demand] demand1_,
 EmploymentRegistration.[AttachmentType] attachment5_ where ttachment0_.DemandId=demand1_.DemandId 
 and demand1_.PersonId=person3_.PartyId and person3_.PartyId=birthcerti4_.PersonId and
 attachment0_.AttachmentTypeId=attachment5_.AttachmentTypeId 
 and (demand1_.TraceCode like ('%'+?+'%') or birthcerti4_.NationalNumber like ('%'+?+'%'))
 and   attachment5_.ShowDuringRegistration=?
```

the inner exception :`{"Specified cast is not valid."}`

```
protected void AddExpression(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression);  this method get an experssion and append that expression to the linq query 



 public class AttachmentTypeMap : ClassMap<AttachmentType>
{
    public AttachmentTypeMap()
    {
        Schema("EmploymentRegistration");

        Id(p => p.Id);//int identity

        Map(p => p.Title);//string

        Map(p => p.ShowDuringRegistration);//byte

        Map(p => p.ScriptName)
            .Length(100);

        References(p => p.EmploymentLicense);
    }
}`
```

by  executing a simpler query like this:

```
 Repository<AttachmentType>.FindAll().Where(p=>p.ShowDuringRegistration==(byte)1).Tolist();
```

that will be generated like this
    select cast(count(*) as INT) as col_0_0_ from 
    EmploymentRegistration.[AttachmentType]   attachment0_ left outer join
    EmploymentRegistration. [EmploymentLicense] employment1_
     on   attachment0_.EmploymentLicenseId=employment1_.EmploymentLicenseId where
     attachment0_.ShowDuringRegistration=?

when i wanna know the number of returned value by

```
int _totalItems = Query.Count();  //Query is IQueryable<T>
```

i'll see the error again

even by just executing this query the error would raise exactly like before:

```
//ShowDuringRegistration  is byte?
var data= Repository<AttachmentType>.Find(p => p.ShowDuringRegistration == 0)
                                    .ToList();
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{

   IQueryable<T> Find();

    IQueryable<T> Find(object id);

    IQueryable<T> FindBySpecification(ISpecification<T> specification);

    IQueryable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression);

}


 public static class Repository<T> where T : class
{

private static IRepository<T> Current
    {
        get { return UnitOfWork.GetRepository<T>(); }
    }

 public static IQueryable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        return Current.Find(expression);
    }

 public static IList<T> FindAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        return Current.FindAll(expression);
    }

}
```

Comment: Now you've introduced `FindAll` - what's that? Your code is still pretty unclear, to be honest - and the typo of `Tolist` instead of `ToList` suggests this isn't *really* your code. If you could show a short but *complete* example, that would really help. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints.

Comment: Based on the discussion so far, the definition of AttachmentType is probably to blame. You really need to post a stack trace if you want further help though.

Answer (score 3):

You're not actually using a byte - you're using an `int`. It normally works in C# because `ShowDuringRegistration`  would be promoted to an `int` and then the comparison would be made. Try this instead:

```
public AttachmentSearchSpecification WithAttachmentTypeShowDuringRegistration
    (bool showDuringRegistration=false)
{
    byte value = showDuringRegistration ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0;

    AddExpression(p => p.AttachmentType.ShowDuringRegistration == value);
    return this;
}
```

Comment: thank u but it didnt work,as i told even if i pass a byte to that method it wouldnt work

Comment: @Adrakadabra: "It didn't work" is pretty vague. Please give the exact details of where it's failing, and ideally a stack trace too. You said you *were* "sending" a byte, but didn't show any code... it wasn't clear what you meant.

Comment: @Adrakadabra: Please put that into your post instead of as a comment. It's not clear why the SQL has a count in, either... Could you show what `AddExpression` does?

Comment: @Jon: i dont know what is that cast in sql generated query, because that byte property is not an identity property!

Comment: @Adrakadabra: What happens if you remove all the other requirements? Focus on a *minimal* example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Jon: could u plz have a look at what i wrote, i mean i just edit my post with simpler query

Comment: @Adrakadabra: We still don't know what `Repository<T>.Find` looks like. A *complete* program would be really useful...